# React Redux issue delivering state value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, state

I'm trying to show which values I choose from a select option of a component which has been populated previously using useSelector hook (I am not allowed to use React Select Library).

My problem is first time I select it, I got an empty array returned. Getting populated with first chosen value when is selected by second time. Every subsequent select, populate the array with the previous action value

Here is the related code:

```
const valueTemp = useSelector((state) => state.temperaments)

const [input, setInput] = useState({
    name: "",
    height_min: "",
    height_max: "",
    weight_min: "",
    weight_max: "",
    life_min: "",
    life_max: "",
    image: "",
    temperament: [],
 })

 var arrTemps=[];

  function showValues(){
    for(var i = 0; i < input.temperament.length; i++){
      for(var j=0; j < valueTemp.length;j++){
        if(parseInt(input.temperament[i])===valueTemp[j].id){
          arrTemps.push(valueTemp[j].name)
        }
      }
    }
    return arrTemps;
  }

var showMe="" ;
  function handleSelect(e){  
    setInput({
        ...input, temperament:[...input.temperament, e.target.value ]
    })  
    showMe=showValues() 
    console.log(showMe) 
    document.getElementById('mostrame').innerText=showMe;
  }
<select className={style.orderLarge} onChange={handleSelect}>
   <option value="">Temperaments:</option>
     {
       valueTemp.map((e) => (
         <option key={e.id} value={e.id}>{e.name}</option>              
       ))
     }
</select>
      
 <div id="mostrame"style={{color:'burlywood'}}>Temperamentos:</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you were doing all looping logics for. As far as I understood you just needed the history of your dropdown. I will add my version of your code.

Your select was an uncontrol element. I have added `value` on that so now react controls it. Your history `History: {[...input.temperament]}` is available after the select. The selected value is the last item in the array. Instead of `document.getElementById('mostrame').innerText=showMe;` you can directly use the last selected value like I have done. You are not recommended to access DOM elements like you are doing. Display your selected item name as as shown. Everything is working because I am converting the selected value into a NUMBER. When you select an item value returned is a string. You need to convert that to a number if you are using number. `temperament: [...input.temperament, +e.target.value]`. Adding + will convert a string to number.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const valueTemp = [
    { id: 1, name: 'abc' },
    { id: 2, name: 'efg' },
    { id: 3, name: 'hij' }
  ];

  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    temperament: []
  });

  function handleSelect(e) {
    setInput({
      ...input,
      temperament: [...input.temperament, +e.target.value]
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <select
        onChange={handleSelect}
        value={input.temperament[input.temperament.length - 1]}
      >
        <option value="">Temperaments:</option>
        {valueTemp.map(e => (
          <option key={e.id} value={e.id}>
            {e.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <div>History: {[...input.temperament]}</div>
   <div>
    History Values: 
    {input.temperament.map(i => valueTemp.find(v => v.id === i)?.name+", 
     ")}
  </div>
  <div>Selected value =
  {
    valueTemp.find(
      v => v.id === input.temperament[input.temperament.length - 1]
    )?.name
  }</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Tnx a lot for your help Sanish! Im doing all those looping logic due im a noob in hes path to became Fullstacker. Your version has teach me a valuable lesson. But still aint get an array of name results. Your code shows an id history...  I need a name history to final user can see wich parameters has been choose: like Temperaments: Aloof, Confident, Guardian instead of 5,12.23

Comment: With my current logic, it is easy to get those values also into history.  `input.temperament.map(i => valueTemp.find(
      v => v.id === i
    )?.name
)`

Comment: You're totally right Sanish. Once again: thank you.My respects.